# How to automatically decompress a custom compressed file when opened in emacs?

Tags: unix, emacs, elisp

I know Emacs automatically opens compressed files like `.tar.gz`. I'm trying to figure how to achieve this with my own compression script rather than the standard ones.
Following [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-support/39pyRbIO0FA), I added the following to my Emacs init file

```
(if (fboundp 'auto-compression-mode)
    (auto-compression-mode 0)
  (require 'jka-compr)) 
(add-to-list 'jka-compr-compression-info-list 
             ["\\.customcom\\'"
              "custom compressing"  "customcom" (-c)
              "custom decompressing" "customcom" (-d)
              nil t])
(auto-compression-mode 1)
```

Ideally, i want to run the command `customcom -d foo.customcom` when the file is opened but with the above addition, its running `customcom -d < foo.cusotmcom` and giving an error. How can I modify the above to nullify the input redirection so that it takes the filename only rather than the contents of the file or is there a different way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, the following code is helpful. By the way, it is interesting that the author of `jka-compr` did not take the evaluation of the program arguments into consideration and did not provide `filename` as one of the possible evaluable arguments.

I do not know your compression/uncompression program. Therefore, I just used `cat` for files ending with `.cat` instead for testing.

```lisp
(defadvice jka-compr-info-compress-args (around eval-args activate)
  "Evaluate program arguments"
  (setq ad-return-value (mapcar 'eval (aref info 3))))

(defadvice jka-compr-info-uncompress-args (around eval-args activate)
  "Evaluate program arguments"
  (setq ad-return-value (mapcar 'eval (aref info 6))))


(add-to-list 'jka-compr-compression-info-list ["\\.cat\\'" "cat" "cat" ("-")
                           "cat uncompress" "cat" (filename) nil t ""])

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cat\\'" nil jka-compr))

(add-to-list 'file-name-handler-alist '("\\.cat\\'" . jka-compr-handler))
```

Corresponding enhancement-request:

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?msg=5;att=1;bug=16454

Comment: This is pure genius. I was not aware there's a way to extend existing functionality in the init file without patching the source. Can you recommend a good elisp book. I'm only 1 month into my solid emacs use.

Comment: I have filed an enhancement request to 'bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org'. The title is 'Enhancement: emacs library jka-compr'. I do not know when it reaches the list. This enhancement includes the evaluation of the program arguments. As @stefan noted advices _are_ evil for production code. So let us hope that they accept the enhancement. For an introduction to elisp see `C-h i Emacs Lisp Intro`. More enhanced stuff is in `C-h i Elisp`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to test this without knowing what your custom compression and decompression tools are, but using `xargs` seems to work for me on Linux:

```lisp
(if (fboundp 'auto-compression-mode)
    (auto-compression-mode 0)
  (require 'jka-compr))

(add-to-list 'jka-compr-compression-info-list
             ["\\.customcomm\\'"
              "custom compressing" "xargs" ("customcom" "-c")
              "custom decompressing" "xargs" ("customcom" "-d")
              nil t])

(auto-compression-mode 1)
```

Note that you may still have problems if the output of this command is not to `STDOUT`.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try and use `("-d" "-")` as argument, in case `customcom` follows the custom of interpreting `-` to mean "use stdin".  Or depending on your OS, you could try `("-d" "/dev/stdin")`: it should work under GNU/Linux at least.