# How to automatically compress (using custom script) file when saving in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

This question is a follow up to my earlier question [How to automatically decompress a custom compressed file when opened in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118197/how-to-automatically-decompress-a-custom-compressed-file-when-opened-in-emacs). Based on that, I was able tweak my init.el as follows

```
(defadvice jka-compr-info-compress-args (around eval-args activate) 
   "Evaluate program arguments"  
   (setq ad-return-value (mapcar 'eval (aref info 3))))

(defadvice jka-compr-info-uncompress-args (around eval-args activate) 
   "Evaluate program arguments" 
   (setq ad-return-value (mapcar 'eval (aref info 6))))

(add-to-list 'jka-compr-compression-info-list
          ["\\.tk\\'"                                                                      
          "TKing"   "tksave"  (filename) 
          "unTKing" "tkopen" (filename) 
           nil t ""])
```

"tk" is a custom compression tool that is being used internally in my custom. "tksave" and "tkopen" are the corresponding commands for compressing and decompressing respectively. "tkopen" is working fine by automatically uncompressing when I open a file but "tksave" saves the original file back rather the edited buffer visiting the file. How can I compress back the edited buffer to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `defadvice` hacks and instead of your `tksave` and `tkopen` use programs which work as "unix filters" (i.e. take their input from stdin and send their output to stdout).

For `tkopen` you might get away with running `tkopen /dev/stdin`.  And maybe for `tksave` you might also get away with `tksave /dev/stdin`.  But both of those depend on exactly how those two commands work (e.g. if you do `tkopen /foo/bar` where is the uncompressed result sent?  Same for `tksave /foo/bar`).